# big-O proof with power functions

Tags: asymptotics, exponentiation

I was wondering if anyone could show a proof for why $a^x$ is $\mathcal{O}(b^x)$ if $a$ and $b$ are constants and $a < b$. In other words, with power functions, does the function with the largest base always eventually overtake a function with a smaller base?

Comment: When writing big-O notation (and similar) you should specify $x \to \infty$.  The answer may be different for other cases, such as $x \to 0^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $0<a<b$. Then
$$
\frac{a^x}{b^x}=\Bigl(\frac{a}{b}\Bigr)^x\le1\quad\forall x\ge0
$$
since $0<a/b<1$. In fact,
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{a^x}{b^x}=0.
$$

By the way, $a^x$ is usually called an *exponential* function, not a power function. This term is used for $x^a$.